# struct not keeping sorted order (swift4)

Tags: ios, sorting, struct, nsuserdefaults, swift4

My code has 2 textfields one for int and the other for string. The way the code is supposed to be sorted is by ascending alphabetical order for the string (a-z)then by descending order for the int (9-1).So i entered 2 entries in a,2 a,1 order but the way the list is being displayed is a,2 a,1 which is not the sorted order. How can I keep the sorted order?

VIEWCONTROLLER

```
  @IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {
        yourArray.append((textA.text!))
        number.append(Int(textB.text!)!)
        let tuples = zip(yourArray,number)

        let sorted = tuples.sorted(by: { this, next in
            if this.0 < next.0 {
                return true
            } else if this.0 == next.0 {
                return this.1 < next.1
            } else {
                return false
            }})
        bad.mm.append(String(describing:  sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")))
    }
    struct bad {
    static var mm = [String]()}
```

VIEWCONTROLLER2

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(benCarson.text, forKey: "SavedStringArray2")
    defaults.synchronize()


    benCarson.text = String(describing: bad.mm)
    benCarson.numberOfLines = 5000

}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between the two view controllers?  How does the data get from view controller 1 to vc2?  What is `bad.mm`?  Your code isn’t using structs at all and all of those forced unwraps are a bad idea too. Also, you shouldn’t use `describing` for anything other than debugging, but for all that it does produce the sort you want, so the problem is in code not shown

Comment: The sort algorithm is fine (tho something like `let sorted = tuples.sorted { this, next in this.0 == next.0 ? this.1 < next.1 : this.0 < next.0 }` would be more concise). The problem undoubtedly rests in how you're showing the results (e.g. you show two different routines, one where you update the text field and another where you set the string, but don't show us how one relates to the other).

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the struct where bad.mm is implemented. At the bottom of VIEWCONTROLLER. Hope that helps thanks.

Comment: can you post the sample `tuples` value? if my tuples is like this `zip(["a","a"],["2","1"])` I am able to get the sorted array.

Comment: Note that `Int(textB.text!)!` would crash your app if the user inputs any non digits to that text field. Even if you have set your keyboard type the user can still paste some text on it.

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your structures  starting with an uppercase letter. `String(describing:` method it is probably not what you want. And there is no need to force synchronize.

Comment: If you need to display all strings in your array as a single string you should use `Bad.mm.joined(bySeparator: ", ")` method to join your strings into a single one.

Comment: @ViniApp if you post a, a the app will crash. I know this is bad practice but I am just trying to get this to work betting on the user will not make a mistake.

Comment: @Rob your code is definitely better. I updated my code any suggestions.